# How to align two fields

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I'm currently using this snippet of code to get one label and its related select field displayed in row. But the final output shows two lines. The first displays the label and the second just displays the select. How to make them displayed as only one row, please?

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="SE">OS</label>
        <select id="SE" name="SE" class="form-control">

                <option value="os">os</option>

        </select>
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do with `form-horizontal`

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="SE" class="col-sm-2 control-label">OS</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <select id="SE" name="SE" class="form-control">
            <option value="os">os</option>
        </select>
    </div>
  </div> 
</form>
```

**Demo here:** http://www.bootply.com/mLjxWBX7BS

**Documentation:** http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `form-group` use [form-inline](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline). It was designed for this purpose.

`<div class="form-inline">`

**[DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/rBtHPcaXs4)**